# App crashes on a simple activity switch .... when a button is pressed

Tags: android, crash

okay so i have a simple java activity file which just switches activity when a button is pressed. now my animation is working fine... the first activity also opens just fine... the Rts button also works fine .... but the reset button when clicked instead of changing activity as comanded it crashes the app... i cant understand the problem ... no error or problem is being shown.... only log cat goes crazy when i test it.. please help...

```
public class Title extends Activity {

Button reset, rts;
ImageView title;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_title);
    Animation a = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.animator.animation);
     ImageView rImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.title);
     rImage.startAnimation(a);
     func();

     reset = (Button) findViewById(R.id.reset);
     reset.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

         @Override
           public void onClick(View arg0) {
             Intent reset=new Intent(Title.this,MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(reset);
           }
        });



    rts = (Button) findViewById(R.id.rts);
    rts.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View arg0) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    Intent rts=new Intent(Title.this,Rts.class);
                    startActivity(rts);

                }
            });


}

protected void func() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.title, menu);
    return true;
}



}
```

here is the log cat

```
09-10 17:30:22.110: E/dalvikvm-heap(581): Out of memory on a 15681616-byte allocation.
09-10 17:30:22.340: E/AndroidRuntime(581): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-10 17:30:22.340: E/AndroidRuntime(581): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.whattodo2/com.example.whattodo2.Question36}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #7: Error inflating class android.widget.TextView
09-10 17:30:22.340: E/AndroidRuntime(581):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2059)
09-10 17:30:22.340: E/AndroidRuntime(581):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
09-10 17:30:22.340: E/AndroidRuntime(581):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
09-10 17:30:22.340: E/AndroidRuntime(581):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
09-10 17:30:22.340: E/AndroidRuntime(581):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
09-10 17:30:22.340: E/AndroidRuntime(581):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
09-10 17:30:22.340: E/AndroidRuntime(581):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
09-10 17:30:22.340: E/AndroidRuntime(581):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-10 17:30:22.340: E/AndroidRuntime(581):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
09-10 17:30:22.340: E/AndroidRuntime(581):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
09-10 17:30:22.340: E/AndroidRuntime(581):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
09-10 17:30:22.340: E/AndroidRuntime(581):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
09-10 17:30:22.340: E/AndroidRuntime(581): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #7: Error inflating class android.widget.TextView
09-10 17:30:22.340: E/AndroidRuntime(581):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:613)
09-10 17:30:22.340: E/AndroidRuntime(581):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
09-10 17:30:22.340: E/AndroidRuntime(581):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:660)
09-10 17:30:22.340: E/AndroidRuntime(581):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:685)
09-10 17:30:22.340: E/AndroidRuntime(581):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746)
09-10 17:30:22.340: E/AndroidRuntime(581):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
09-10 17:30:22.340: E/AndroidRuntime(581):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
09-10 17:30:22.340: E/AndroidRuntime(581):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
```

and here is the xml for main activity

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@drawable/background"
             >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/q4y"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="300dip"

        android:layout_margin="15dip"
        android:background="@drawable/paper"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="25dip"
        android:text="@string/bored"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="35sp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/bNo"
        android:layout_width="80dip"
        android:layout_height="80dip"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/bYes"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/bYes"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/q4y"
        android:layout_marginLeft="40dip"
        android:layout_marginRight="15dip"
        android:background="@drawable/no" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/bYes"
        android:layout_width="80dip"
        android:layout_height="80dip"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/q4y"
        android:layout_below="@+id/q4y"
        android:layout_marginTop="80dip"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/bNo"
        android:layout_marginRight="40dip"
        android:background="@drawable/yes"
        />



    </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Filter logcat by "error" and post the output. Also, possibly the `onCreate()` of `MainActivity,java`. Also be sure that `reset` is the `id` of a `Button` in `activity_title.xml`.

Comment: Also, does `func()` do anything right now?

Comment: okay so the button id is reset... i dont know the func() it was just something i copy pasted for animation and it works so i guess it does something... and log cat is very long even after filter

Comment: At least post some of the logcat. Look for something that says "Fatal Exception" then Caused by and it should have a line after that which references your app. Post the first part that has those lines I mentioned and everything in between them. You are probably getting all errors in your app and not filtering by runtime errors

Comment: Also, you could do some debugging by setting breakpoints and see where it crashes. If it makes it past the `Intent` and `startActivity` call then follow it through the `onCreate()` of the called `Activity`

Comment: i tried posting the log cat i hope u understand it

Comment: @user2643867 post the xml also

Comment: xml posted .. see it again please

Answer (score 0):

```
       @Override
       public void onClick(View arg0) {
         Intent resetIntent=new Intent(Title.this,MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(resetIntent);
       }
       });
```

Try this for reset button. Does it work?

Comment: Intent name for reset button was `reset`, that is also the Button name. Understand?

Comment: I do understand but it was a subtle difference. That's why explanations as to *why* your suggestion should work goes a long way with answers.

Comment: Yeah you re right, sorry for that. BTW that's not the problem seeing just now the LogCat

Comment: post XML please for MainActivity

Comment: No problem, just trying to help. Some explanation is always a good idea to help the OP understand *why* your code should work.

Comment: xml posted guys ... see now please

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to post more information for a better answer. But looking at the code, you are creating an Intent correctly and calling startActivity(intent) correctly. My guess is your forgot to declare the activity in your AndroidManifest.

```
<activity
    android:name="com.example.package.Rts" />
```

Chances are if you figure out Logcat, it will tell you that you need to declare your activity. If this isn't your answer, you'll have to post the stack trace

Comment: Binary XML file line #7: Error inflating class android.widget.TextView
09-10 17:30:22.340: E/AndroidRuntime(581):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2059). this does not answer the question. op should get activitynotfoundexcpetion if there is not an entry in manifest

Comment: The problem is also with the `reset Button`. The op said the other works fine

Comment: could it possibly be that MainActivity is actually running in the background? so when you try to inflate it, its already inflated? try calling finish() when you leave MainActivity